# Can someone break this propositional logic formulae down via truth table?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is my first day learning about logic and logic programming, I have been doing some exercises using a truth table for propositional logic questions.

$$p ∧ (q ∨ r ) ≡ (p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∧ r )$$

Using a truth table I worked out that this statement is false, but I don't know whether this is correct. If someone could break this down for me or point me to a resource i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a truth table for your propositional statement 
$$
  p\wedge(q \vee r) \;\;\equiv\;\; (p \wedge q)\vee(p \wedge r)
$$
Notice that the last two columns are identical, so the statement is true.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
  p&q&r&(q \vee r)&(p \wedge q)&(p \wedge r)&p\wedge(q \vee r)&(p \wedge q)\vee(p \wedge r)\\\hline
  T&T&T&T&T&T&T&T\\
  T&T&F&T&T&F&T&T\\
  T&F&T&T&F&T&T&T\\
  T&F&F&F&F&F&F&F\\
  F&T&T&T&F&F&F&F\\
  F&T&F&T&F&F&F&F\\
  F&F&T&T&F&F&F&F\\
  F&F&F&F&F&F&F&F\\
\end{array}